# Is there any documentation or article on how IICS IPU is calculated for different services (CDI, CAI, MI etc)

Tags: informatica, iics, iics-di, iics-mi, iics-ai

I did some research online and couldn't find how exactly the IPU is calculated. The only information I got is the different scalars used for different services.

Is there any specific formula where the server type (CPU, memory) is a function, for the calculation?

Comment: https://www.informatica.com/products/cloud-integration/pricing.html

Comment: That's just the sales page. it does not say how the IPU is calculated.

Comment: I don't think there is an official formula and price list. I think this is negotiable and you need to contact sales rep to discuss the details.

Comment: I know the price per IPU can be different for different customers. What I am interested is how IPU is calculated. For example, CDI tasks uses Compute Units. I am assuming this has to be function of the server type we use.